# How to get the information about installer version of executable?

Tags: windows-installer, unattended, installshield

I have such a question: lets assume I downloaded an executable program, for example: Opera.exe or OpenOffice.org or SomeWifiDriver.msi.

I found out that any program can be created mostly with such installators: Windows Installer, InstallShield, PackagefortheWeb, InstallShield with MSI, Wise InstallMaster, Inno Setup, Ghost installer etc.

Is there some tool or some commands for commnad line or anything else - to get exactly information with which installer software was created some concrete program? Thanks!

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start the installer, you will often see the branding for the packager if its most of those... For example Installshield *always* brands the installer.

Others, you can right click and extract (I like 7zip) and see what is dropped, sometimes you will see an MSI or other good information.

You can also use the command prompt to get switches and sometimes that will tell you. If you run myInstall.exe /? and MSI switches pop up, then it is an MSI.

There is no concrete, always tells you exactly right, what package builder was used to my knowledge though

Answer (score 2):

There's no sure-fire way to always see the right one, but you'd have to look for the turdlets left behind by each individual method.

Sometimes you can right-click the file, and within Summary, might display the application.  Other times, the executable will have the details within the splash screen.